# how to send view file variable by jquery in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

Suppose we have variable v1 which carry value 'abc' in view file i.e index.ctp. Now we have to  pass this variable in data while ajax url load.

Comment: have you got your answer see my update answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var v1 = "abc";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "your url where you want to send data",
    data: {
        passval: v1
    },
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {},
    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {},
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
});
```

in `php` file where you recieve get data by

```
$_POST['passval'];// gives "Abc"
```

see **[ajax demo how it setup](http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/ajax/)**

**UPDATE**

**set php variable in javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var MyJSStringVar = "<?php Print($MyPHPStringVar); ?>"; 
var MyJSNumVar = <?php Print($MyPHPNumVar); ?>;
 </script>
```

Comment: before javascript. we have v1=abc in view file

Comment: var v1 = "<?php echo $abc; ?>"; where $abc carry value from controller action and it is render in view..while in writing into JavaScript don't know how to get this variable..normally in JavaScript we can get data from id, class

Comment: <?php $v1 = 'abc'; ?> and at script <script>var v1 = "<?php echo $abc; ?> </script>

Comment: <script>var v1 = '<?php echo $abc; ?>' </script> if you are get your solution then accept as an answer :)

Comment: no, it doesn't work becoz $abc variable comes from server side and it can't extract in client side script..